# Tree climbing in distress

Tags: tree-climbing

There seems to be a **legend that in a stressful situation** (such as, trying to escape a bear, a boar or other large animals), **people can climb trees that they normally could not.** Not *would* not, but literally *could* not. **Is this true**?

Given the presumed rarity of these situations, and their circumstances, I do not expect an available dataset of such incidents, with reliable conclusions properly mined out of them. I am interested in any informed opinion on this matter.

FWIW tigers are reportedly rather clumsy climbers (except for cubs) but it seems to be the case that a tiger will climb a tree when being chased, or when after prey. The site also gives this interesting bit:

> Despite their incredible muscle power tigers need to enter a tree at a
>   run, being unable to simply pull themselves up in the manner used by
>   leopards.

[-- "Lairweb" --](http://www.lairweb.org.nz/tiger/tree.html)

If the ability to climb trees in humans is enhanced by stress, what are some major contributing factors? (E.g., a better ability to muster energy, willingness to take risks, readines to ignore minor injuries -- scratches etc.)

I am also curious about the kind of trees that can be climbed in this way -- e.g., can humans be driven to [mast climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_climbing) on a tree when in distress, although they ``normally'' cannot climb a mast?

Comment: I don't know where I could verify this, but my father once told me about a man whose boat was wrecked in a storm off the west coast of Ireland. He was found at the top of the cliff, but had no recollection of climbing it.

Comment: The difference between 'wouldn't' and 'couldn't' isn't as clear as you seem to suggest, given the psychological aspect,  but there are plenty of tales of unusual feats of strength in desperate situations, some of which are well documented.

Comment: Adrenaline is a wonderful thing at times.

Comment: @ChrisH I am not sure a mere physical strength (even under adrenaline) will help, if you really do not know how to climb up.

Comment: @anemone but you said nothing about knowing how, instead implying that physical ability was important

Comment: @ChrisH That is not my reading of what I wrote. As one example, in climbing a (tree that is shaped like a) mast, where do I suggest that mast-climbing depends on strength?

Comment: Put it this way: when your life is in peril, you don't go "Oooh I don't think I can do that," or "I know sycamore trees but not ash trees." You just get on with whatever is necessary, as a more instinctive part of the brain takes charge. It's not about taking risks, when the major risk has already put you into "fight or flight" mode and the risk is in doing nothing. Either that, or you haven't understood the danger.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with you completely. In asking the question as I have done, I am looking for more specific information on climbing a tree, which is mostly a nontrivial feat, and a nuanced view of how far this "instinct" can take me. Of course, for example when in danger presumably one runs faster, but I guess there is a limit to how fast a person can run compared to what they "normally" can do in this respect, and it is not clear whether one can run overall "better" (e.g., without tripping). Climbing a tree is just a nice example of this problem, and one I've often wondered about.